# iOS development - How to choose only jpeg, png and gif image file with UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm wanted to do something like web page that only allowed user to view only jpeg, png and gif file types from ImagePickerController. The reason I want to do this is because my server only accept those file types.

Anyone know how to do it? Or any better solution for it?

Comment: UIImagePickerController wont give you a File per se, it will give you a UIImage that you can use later to convert to any type of image you want before uploading to a server. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Comment: Here is how to convert an image into png. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597710/how-to-convert-all-image-format-into-png-format