# How to convert jpg images to png images from server

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Hi can anyone help in converting jpg images fetching from server into png images in objective-c.

Actually the problem is through the app,we are sharing images on facebook,but when jpg image is uploading in server,the image is not shared in facebook.

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageurl]]];

I have to convert the imageurl to png format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
UIImage *img; // Your image coming from server
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img); // Convert it in to PNG data
UIImage *pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData]; // Result image
```

Comment: If underlying image data cannot be converted into PNG format, then `pngData` will be `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

after you retrieve your images/url save them this way:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12597758/2982379)

Comment: Don't you think, you should give credit to the original [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12597758/1603072)?

Comment: By credit, I mean you should provide link of that answer in yours one(if you are taking reference from that answer) and here in this case(you just copy-pasted someone's answer or in other words similar question available), you can mark the question as duplicate(in stead of providing answer).

Comment: It would be even better to just flag this as a duplicate.  No need to answer the same question again.